# Accessor is not a parameter accessor

Tags: oracle, mdx

im using SSAS 2008 .

my data connection is oracle and whenever im trying to process my cube i got this error (Pic no.1)
[image: connection]

there is column in my fact table that is the measure filed and it's type is Decimal.

when i put a dummy value ('1' for instance) so the process succeeded... so the problem is that decimal filed.

i was trying to cast it to int/varchar and etc but it's not helping. also tried to round it...
[image: accessors]

can anyone help plz?

another error i get in pic 2....something regarding a key....
[image: key]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a data type issue. Try rounding your number or casting the number to a decimal with a lower precision.  Here is a [similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6d88c43-6c4d-4f7d-ab2f-8a33f0729315/partition-process-error?forum=sqlanalysisservices)n on MSDN.

Another suggestion from a quick google search is to make sure you are using the most current OLEDB provider for Oracle.